# $(e.target) != divObject

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to see if the $(e.target) != to a div object I created.

Here is my object

```
var newDiv = $("<div>").addClass("dropDown");
```

I am attempting to match that object with my on click command.

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    if(!$(e.target) == newDiv)
    {
         //Do something
    }
});
```

How do I reference a name of some sort that the two could match or not?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is` method:

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if ( !$(e.target).is(newDiv) ) {
      // ...
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eRPfr/

Comment: If you were going to go this way, then this would be a bit more efficient: `if (!newDiv.is(e.target))` since you don't have to create a new jQuery object just to do the comparison, though just comparing DOM objects directly like in my answer is probably even more efficient.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, you are right, your suggestion is much efficient than mine.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code:

```
if(!$(e.target) == newDiv)
```

is comparing two separate jQuery objects to see if they are the same object.  That will never be true because they aren't the same object.  That comparison doesn't look to see if the DOM object in each jQuery object is the same, but you could do that like this:

```
if(e.target != newDiv[0])
```